# How can I drop items from a TensorFlow queue when they have been enqueued for too long?

Tags: queue, tensorflow

I would like to push items to a TensorFlow queue, and if they have not been pulled out after some timeout they just get dropped (kind of like burgers at McDonald's). Right now I add a timestamp to each item and just ignore the items whose timestamp is too old. This works fine except that the old items take up some space in the queue: is there anyway to drop old items in the middle of the queue as well?

Comment: why doesn't verifying the timestamp when dequeuing work?

Comment: It kinda works, yes, but suppose you have a client gathering live data and pushing it to the queue. Suppose the puller client that dequeues the data crashes or slows down for some reason. The queue will fill up, and the live data pusher will get blocked, missing out on fresh data. When the puller comes back to life, it will dequeue and drop every item and the live data pusher will start pushing data again, but there will be no fresh data at all for the puller to chew. It's probably fairly easy to work around on the pusher side, but I was hoping for a TF solution. :)

Comment: this seems to be something for https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/ however I'm not sure it has such a feature

Comment: What queue are you using? You should have only filenames in memory in the case of images.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. None of the [Tensorflow Queue operations](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#QueueBase) provide such functionality.